# Libgdx with Google Play Services Login

Tags: java, libgdx, google-play-services

So I'm not quite sure how to handle Google Play Services Login with libgdx, i mean i'd like to ask for user login at the start of application. So my first try was to implement login in `AndroidLauncher`'s `onCreate` method like this

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        startSignInIntent();
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MainGame(this), config);
    }
```

At first it looks like it works fine, fist time opening app it asks to me to login, then on next app openings in doesn't. But the problem here is that `initialize` method is called no matter if `startSignInIntent`succeed, and i'd like to let it call `initialize` only when login is a success, and possibly close the app if it fails, and let user try again by opening my application again. I tried to call initialize in `OnActivityResult`, in `result.isSuccess()`, but it doens't work that way, i guess it has to be called in `onCreate`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if(result.isSuccess()) {

                userAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
                Log.i("GoogleAccountTest", "Login Successful");


            } else {

                String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
                if(message == null || message.isEmpty()) {

                    message = "Something went wrong";

                }

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message).setNeutralButton("Ok", null).show();

            }

        }

    }
```

Then i tried to make my own login screen with just one button to login with google, i created an Interface, implemented it in `AndroidLauncher` and passed it along my initialize method to then call `.startSignInIntent()`, but the problem is i'm still not catching weather the call is successful or not here.

How should i implement Google Play Services Login in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so few days later if anyone wants to know how i handled it, that's my solution:

I created additional screen with Login button, i call `StartSignInIntent` on button press, then in main activity i created a flag that i set to true in  `onActivityResult` when `StartSignInIntent` result is successful. Then in screen with Login Button in render method i check for that flag and when it turns to true i change my screen to Main Menu